# Apache2 - where is <location/> in the config file?

Tags: server, apache2, configuration

Why there is no `<location>` in my Apache2 config file?

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

I can find the `<Directory />` as follows:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But i cannot find  at all. I am trying to allow OPTIONS DELETE PUT methods as follows:

```
<Location "/">
    AllowMethods GET POST OPTIONS DELETE PUT
    Require all granted
</Location>
```

My Apache version:

```
$ apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.38 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2019-08-26T13:31:40
```

Any ideas how to add `AllowMethods GET POST OPTIONS DELETE PUT`?

Answer (score 1):

Because the `<Location>` directives are appropriate for specific needs (rules) and such rules are not appropriate for any default configuration :)

> The `<Location>` directive limits the scope of the enclosed directives
>   by URL. It is similar to the `<Directory>` directive, and starts a
>   subsection which is terminated with a `</Location>` directive.
>   `<Location>` sections are processed in the order they appear in the
>   configuration file, after the `<Directory>` sections and `.htaccess` files
>   are read, and after the `<Files>` sections.
>
> `<Location>` sections operate completely outside the filesystem. This
>   has several consequences. Most importantly, `<Location>` directives
>   should not be used to control access to filesystem locations. Since
>   several different URLs may map to the same filesystem location, such
>   access controls may by circumvented.

- Source: [Apache Core Features: `<Location>` Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#location)

The `<Directory />` directive refers to the root `/` of the filesystem. In other hand **`<Location />`** refers to the base URI -  `http://example.com`**`/`**, where `example.com` is the `ServerName` of a virtual host. So the rules written for `<Location />` will override the rules written for `<Directory /var/www/html>`, where `/var/www/html` is the **`DocumentRoot`** of the particular virtual host.